# Team foundation & workspace

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I have a project on my Computer & on my Laptop which is on TFS 2013 Update 4

When I make changes on my Computer and I use Get Latest Version (Recursive) on my laptop it always say "All files Up to date" then I go to the file which I edited and I would compare it with the Server Version where I can then clearly see the difference. I will then go to the file again, right click, get specific version tick both tickboxes and select Latest version, still the same thing "All file up to date".

Then I would go to Team Explorer select the project and right click and again Get Latest Version (Recursive) which will also say "All file up to date" I will even follow the same steps (specific version + latest and both tick boxes) Sometimes it will get ALL files again, and sometimes it would also just say "All file up to date"

I am using the same tfs username and password on both computers and also the same workspace on both computers.

I am clueless on what to do, I have Visual Studio 2013

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never use the same workspace on multiple machines. Tfs tracks file version per workspace so if laptop has latest it never downloads files again. Create separate workspace and you will be good!